# find xargs paste on several csv files

Tags: bash, csv

I would like to merge csv files horizontally, for example

```sh
cat file1.csv
val1;val2;
cat file2.csv
val3;val4
```

and have the following result :

```sh
val1;val2;val3;val4
```

The paste command is a perfect fit and this works :

```sh
paste file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

I would like to do it in a script. In practice, I have files grouped by prefix and i would like to do the following :

```sh
    for (( i = 0; i < "${#group_by[@]}"; i++ )); do
        echo "sorting results of ${group_by[$i]} commands"
        find $DEST_PATH -type f -name "sorted_${group_by[$i]}.csv" -exec paste '{}' > $DEST_PATH/RESULT.csv \;
        #done
    done
```

So csv files are merged by prefix.

This does not work either :

```sh
find . -type f -name "prefix*.csv" | xargs -I{} paste '{}' > result.csv
```

because files are merged vertically :

```sh
cat result.csv
val1;val2;
val3;val4;
```

How can this be achieved in a similar fashion ?

Comment: I wonder how you get the output `val1;val2;val3;val4` by using `paste file1.csv file2.csv` that is the command you wrote it works? There should be a tab character between `val1;val2;` and `val3;val4` in this usage of `paste` command.

Comment: Are there exactly 2 files in each group (beginning with the same prefix) ?

Comment: There was a small typo, i'm using paste -d0 so there is no tab in the output. There can ben 2 or more files in each group

Comment: Then the accepted answer won't work when there are more than 2 files in a group. It won't merge horizontally in that case.

Comment: Moreover, it could be done simply by a single command: `paste -d';' file*.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this with `-n 2` option in `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name "prefix*.csv" -print0 |
xargs -0 -n 2 paste -d ''
```

```
val1;val2;val3;val4
```